# How to change the information printed by Shake during a build

Tags: shake-build-system

Currently when building Shake outputs lines such as:

```
# gcc (for debugBuild)
```

But that is not informative for our application, so we'd like to print something like:

```
objectFileName.o[configurationFlavour]
```

How can you do that in Shake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is to play with the `Verbosity` field of `shakeVerbosity`, or with `--verbose`. At `Normal` I get:

```
# ghc (for output/self/General/Intern.o output/self/General/Intern.hi)
```

And at `Verbose` I get:

```
ghc -c src\Development/Shake/Classes.hs -isrc -main-is Run.main -odir=output/self -hidir=output/self -i=output/self -DPORTABLE -fwarn-unused-imports
```

If that's not enough you can remove the output from `cmd` with `quietly` and print your own messages with `putNormal`:

```
putNormal "I'm running objectFileName.o in configuration"
quietly $ cmd "gcc -c objectFileName.o"
```